# Truffle migration: invalid number of parameters

Tags: truffle-migration

Truffle migrate: Invalid number of parameters

I have got following two smart contracts (SCs):

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;

contract Phishable {
    address public owner;
    constructor () public{
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    function () external payable {} 
    function withdrawAll(address payable _recipient) public payable {
        require(tx.origin == owner);
        _recipient.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

== and the other one is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;
interface Phishable{  
   function withdrawAll(address payable _recipient ) external;
}
contract PhishableAtt {
    address public owner;
    uint public  count=0;
   
    constructor () public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    function() external payable  { 
      count++; 
      if (count < 2 ) 
         Phishable(msg.sender).withdrawAll(address(msg.sender.balance));
      
   }
}
```

and the migration file is:

```
var victim   = artifacts.require("Phishable");
var attacker = artifacts.require("PhishableAtt");


module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts){
   deployer.deploy(victim).then(function(){
   return deployer.deploy(attacker, victim.address);});
   
};
```

I am getting following error:

> Deploying 'PhishableAtt'    ------------------------
>
> Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***
>
> "PhishableAtt" -- Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 1
> expected 0!.
>
> ```
> at /home/zulfi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.23.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/deployer/src/deployment.js:365:1
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) Truffle v5.1.67 (core: 5.1.67) Node v10.23.3
> ```

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to pass 1 argument to deploy an instance of contract `PhishableAtt`, `deployer.deploy(attacker, victim.address);})`, but the constructor of the `PhishableAtt` contract `constructor () public` takes 0 arguments.

Comment: Please guide me the correct syntax of 2_deploy_contracts.js

Comment: use `deployer.deploy(attacker)` instead of `deployer.deploy(attacker, victim.address)`

Answer (score 0):

The correct 2_deploy_contracts.js is:

```
var Phishable   = artifacts.require("Phishable");
var PhishableAtt = artifacts.require("PhishableAtt");


module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts){
   deployer.deploy(Phishable);
   deployer.deploy(PhishableAtt);
   
};
```